# Go not responding to GET request instantly, it response when ticker is done

Tags: api, go, ticker

I'm new to Go programming and I try to build API for a multiplayer game. If I make GET req to the http://localhost:8080/create_game/gameName . Server response to the request when ticker is done. I need to get response from a server instantly but I got it when ticker is over and game is timeouted and deleted.

Here is my code:

```
var clients = make(map[*websocket.Conn]bool)
var broadcast = make(chan Game)

//GAME_TIMEOUT in seconds
const GAME_TIMEOUT = 20

//ID generating
var genID = 0

var games = []Game{}

var msg json.RawMessage

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}

type GameToSend struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
type Game struct {
    ID    int              `json:"id"`
    Name  string           `json:"name"`
    Timer <-chan time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/create_game/{name}", createGame)
    router.HandleFunc("/game_events", handleConnections)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}

func handleConnections(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    clients[conn] = true
    for _, game := range games {
        conn.WriteJSON(GameToSend{"game.created", game.ID, game.Name})
    }
    for {
        err := conn.ReadJSON(&msg)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(msg)
        }
    }
}

func broadcastGame(game GameToSend) {
    for conn := range clients {
        conn.WriteJSON(game)
    }
}

func createGame(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    genID++
    game := Game{genID, params["name"], time.NewTimer(GAME_TIMEOUT * time.Second).C}
    games = append(games, game)
    broadcastGame(GameToSend{"game.created", game.ID, game.Name})
    w.Write([]byte("response"))
    checkTimeout(genID)
}

func deleteGame(actionType string, i int) {
    for index, game := range games {
        if game.ID == i {
            broadcastGame(GameToSend{actionType, games[index].ID, games[index].Name})
            games = games[:index+copy(games[index:], games[index+1:])]
        }
    }
}

func checkTimeout(id int) {
    for _, game := range games {
        if game.ID == id {
            <-game.Timer
            deleteGame("game.timeout", id)
        }
    }
}
```

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: 1) Don't confuse Timer and Ticker. 2) You are explicitly waiting for all timers to expire with `<-game.Timer`. If you don't want to do that, well, don't do that. It is unclear what your intention is, though, so it's hard to recommend a concrete change.

Comment: my question is, how to get response from server instantly, no matter if timer is expired or not, what is the other way to write when timer is over execute that function without waiting for it?

Comment: There isn't just one way to do this. If you don't need to access the timer anywhere else, [time.AfterFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#AfterFunc) is an obvious choice. You can also run checkTimeout in its own [goroutine](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things you could change, but one of them is in general don't run potentially long running tasks in the code that is responding to clients. Imagine you have millions of games, so many that each call to `checkTimeout` takes a second to iterate over all the games. Every request would have a one second delay to get a complete response, not great. It would be better to signal another goroutine should iterate over the games and clean up expired ones, that way you can return immediately to the client while the clean up happens in the background.

Turns out I misread what you are doing, but the advice is still valid. In this case though the "long running function" actually waits until the timer expires before returning. That could be significantly longer than one second! Were you meaning to run that in a goroutine? `go checkTimeout(genID)`